# Ionic with chart.js always shows white graphic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, charts

I want to show a graphic in an ionic application by using Chart library. I followed the steps explained in differents urls for example in:

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/08/using-charts-in-your-ionic-framework-mobile-app/

This is my code:

tab-dash.html

```
<h1>Simple chart modified</h1>

<div class="chart-container" ng-show="graph.visible">
  <canvas
    class="chart chart-line"
    data="graph.data"
    labels="graph.labels"
    series="graph.series"
    options="graph.options"
    legend="graph.legend"
  >
  </canvas>
</div>
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

<!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
<script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
      .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
  }
</script>-->

<!-- compiled css output -->
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">
<!--
  The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
-->
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">

  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

<!--
  The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
  Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
  have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
-->
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
Declare chart: 

angular.module('starter', ['ionic','chart.js','starter.controllers','starter.services'])

...

 .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

...
```

And in the controllers.js:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.graph = {};
  $scope.graph.visible = false;

  $scope.showGraph = function(yesOrNo) {
    $scope.graph.visible = yesOrNo;
  }

  $scope.graph.data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]];
  $scope.graph.labels = ['hoi', 'doei', 'hallo', 'hee', 'hoi', 'doei', 'hallo', 'hee'];
  $scope.graph.options = {
    animation: false
  };
  $scope.graph.series = ['Series']
  $scope.graph.legend = true;

})
```

However, when i load the application in the simulator and in the browser, my canvas always is white and nothing is visible. No error is displayed by console.

Can someone tell me what can be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: show your html part which shows your graphic

Comment: Sorry I have edit the post for add the html. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the chart.js module definition to:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services','chart.js'])
```

Verify the markup in the view, only if you are using the recent versions of chart.js (required for 2.x):

```
<canvas
    class="chart chart-line"
    chart-data="graph.data"
    chart-labels="graph.labels"
    chart-series="graph.series"
    chart-options="graph.options"
    chart-legend="graph.legend">
  </canvas>
```